# Preventing Duplicate Integers in Array

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, unique

I'm making an program for class that calls for the program to create 6 randomly generated integers in the range 1-40 and put them into an array. The integers have to be unique so there can't be a situation where a number certain number repeats. The array is then passed onto another method that sorts the array in ascending order. My problem is that I can't get my code to generate 6 unique numbers. My code is as follows:

```
private static void getComputer(int computerNumbers, int[] cN)
{
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < computerNumbers;)
    {
        int computerStored = randomNumbers.nextInt(39)+1;
            if (computerStored == cN[0] || computerStored == cN[1] || computerStored == cN[2] || 
                computerStored == cN[3] || computerStored == cN[4] || computerStored == cN[5])
                continue;
            else
                computerStored = cN[i];
                i++;
    }
}
```

The above block of code outputs an array of 0,0,0,0,0,0. I just can't find out why. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Just for clarification, I know how to do a basic randomgenerator.

```
private static void getComputer(int computerNumbers, int[] cN)
{
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < computerNumbers; i++)
        cN[i] = randomNumbers.nextInt(39)+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant

```
cN[i] = computerStored;
```

Note also that there are three issues with this code: You're passing in the size of the array, which is bad form in Java, you can never get zero (which is technically not a bug in this case since you're dealing with just 1-40), and your conditional is really unwieldy. Instead, I'd do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cN.length;) {
    int candidate = randomNumbers.nextInt(39) + 1;

    // actually, I'd either move this into another method or use a `Set` in the first place
    boolean duplicate = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < i || !duplicate; j++)
        if(candidate == cN[j])
            duplicate = true;

    if(!duplicate)
        cN[i++] = candidate;
}
```

Comment: WOW. Could such a small difference really be the answer? I tried it and it worked. Thank you. Why exactly does this solve the problem?

Comment: @user3577449 `computerStored = cN[i]` means "put the value of `cN[i]` into `computerStored`", and the other way means "put the value of `computerStored` into `cN[i]`". Programming instructions are very specific, and the computer will do exactly what you say, not what you meant to say but didn't.

Comment: It solves the problem because you were reassigning the generated `computerStored` value by placing it on the left of the = operator. So the array was never being updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in a different way:

- create a list of integers 1-40
- shuffle them
- create an array from the first 6 elements

Like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(40);
for (int i = 1; i < 41; i++)
    list.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(list);
int[] cN = new int[6];
for (int i = 0; i < cN.length; i++)
    cN[i] = list.get(i);
```

The advantage of this approach is you don't have to deal with the issue of duplicates, and it makes use of the JDK to do the randomizing.